# Iphone can not load certain asp.net web form page over wifi but can over cellcular data

Tags: asp.net, iphone

I have a web application built on asp.net webform. My web application can run smoothly on android but on iphone I only run it when using cellcular data.

When using wifi, the web page can not load.

I have tried following ways but not resolve this issue:

- Reset network setting, router.
- Clear web history, cache.
- Turn on javascript, check cookies, check if using vpn and blocked webwites.
- Update current wifi DNS.
- Run Safari under private mode.

Please help me if anyone have experience on this issue, thanks.